# Does every open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contain $n$ linearly independent elements?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If so, would be grateful for any references.

Comment: Do you mean that the entire vectors are contained in the ball, or that the heads of the vectors are in the ball but the tails are at the origin?

Comment: Yeah the question, as it stands now, is kind of ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the heads of the vectors only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way, the answer is yes. In fact it's true for an arbitrary open set $U$. Pick a point $P$ of the open set $U$. There's a ball of radius $r$ about $P$ contained in the set. Now the vectors
$$
s~ e_1, s~e_2, \ldots s~ e_n
$$
(based at $P$), where $s = r/2$, are all contained in the ball, and hence in the original set.

Alternatively, picking $u = \min(s, 0.9 \| P \| )$, the endpoints of the (origin-based) vectors $P + ue_1, \ldots, P + u e_n$ are all in the ball and are linearly independent as well (which seems to be what your final response to comments says you want).

Comment: But what about the case in which the ball contains the heads but the tails are at the origin?

Comment: @enzotib: If the tails are at the original and your open set doesn't contain the origin, then my proof fails. But that also suggests that the problem CAN"T mean that, since it's a trivial counterexample. So I'm using a more general notion of vector (a "based vector", which has a basepoint $b$ and direction $d$ (a unit vector), and where containing the vector means containing all point $b + td$ for $0 \le t \le 1$), which seems more like what was probably meant.